# Call a method on a button press held in another class in Android

Tags: android, android-button, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm brand new to Android and I'm trying to test the new Bluetooth LE functionality Android 4.3 has. I've followed the documentation found [here on the Android site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html). But i'm at a stumbling block of actually starting my code.

I was thinking of simply having a button that called my scanLeDevice code, but I can't see anything that can allow me to do this simply. Literally all I have is this class and the sample hello word app they make when you make a new project.

Can anyone help me with this? I know it's noobish, but I'm really stumped.

For reference, my Bluetooth class is this:

```
public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private boolean mScanning;
private Handler mHandler;

// Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

private ArrayAdapter<Object> list;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    list = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    setListAdapter(list);
    scanLeDevice(true);
}

@TargetApi(18)
public void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    list.add("Scanning...");
    final BluetoothAdapter adapter = getBluetoothAdapter();
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;

               // mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                adapter.stopLeScan(callback);
                list.clear();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        adapter.startLeScan(callback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        adapter.stopLeScan(callback);
    }

}
@TargetApi(18)
private BluetoothAdapter getBluetoothAdapter()
{
    BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    return manager.getAdapter();
}
private final BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback callback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() 
{

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        {
            list.add("found: " + device);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    list.add(device);
                    list.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
    }
}
};
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new Button to your MainActivity:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCallMethod"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Call Method" />
```

Put this in the onCreate() of MainActivity

```
addListeners();
```

That's how the addListeners() method should look like in the MainActivity:

```
private void addListeners() {
  Button btnCallMethod = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnCallMethod);

  // CALL METHOD BUTTON
  btnCallMethod.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceScanActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent); // start the DeciveScanActivity
     }
     return false;
   }
 });
}
```

Now call the method in the onCreate() method of the DeviceScanActivity

Don't forget to add your DeviceScanActivity to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
     android:name="com.example.example.DeviceScanActivity"
</activity>
```

Comment: My other class is meant to scan for available bluetooth signals and list them. So I guess that's a form of activity. Really new to android so it's definitions of things is still confusing me.

Comment: Edited my answer. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I've got an error with the DeviceScanActivity.class in the intent call. IDE says it can be resolved as a type. Can you help?

Comment: Is your DeviceScanActivity in another package?

Comment: I simply added another class to my project. I don't know if it is or isn't How do I check?

Comment: You should check that your DeviceScanActivity is declared in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Ah that seems to be the issue. How do I add it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36866/discussion-between-al0x-and-n0xus)